# How do I programatically invoke a Felix/Karaf shell command?

Tags: apache-felix, apache-karaf

I want to automatically invoke the Karaf "dev:watch" command if I detect that I'm running in a dev environment. I've considered adding `dev:watch *` directly to etc/shell.init.script but I don't want it to run unconditionally. So, I'm considering creating a simple service that checks a Java property (something simple like `-Ddevelopment=true`) and invokes org.apache.karaf.shell.dev.Watch itself. I think I can ask OSGi for a Function instance with `(&(osgi.command.function=watch)(osgi.command.scope=dev))` but then I need to create a mock CommandSession just to invoke it. That just seems too complicated. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

Since Apache Karaf 3.0.0 most commands are backed by OSGi services.

So for example the bundle:watch command is using the service
"`org.apache.karaf.bundle.core.BundleWatcher`".

So just bind this service and you can call the bundle:watch functionality very conveniently.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since the question, but I will answer.

You need to use CommandSession class, it is not trivial. [This blog post](http://iocanel.blogspot.com.es/2012/01/advanced-integration-testing-with-pax.html) could guide you. It is related with Pax Exam, but could be applied in any situation. There are more alternatives like using a remote SSH client or even better the remote JXM management console ([reference](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/developers-guide/connect.html)).

Answer (score 0):

The init script can also be used to test for a condition and run a command if that condition is satisfied, so there is no need to create a command session yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The Karaf source itself reveals one answer:

In the KarafTestSupport class which is used for integration testing Karaf itself
(see https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=karaf.git;a=blob;f=itests/src/test/java/org/apache/karaf/itests/KarafTestSupport.java;h=ebdea09ae8c6d926c8e4ac1fae6672f2c00a53dc;hb=HEAD)

The relevant method starts:

```
/**
 * Executes a shell command and returns output as a String.
 * Commands have a default timeout of 10 seconds.
 *
 * @param command    The command to execute.
 * @param timeout    The amount of time in millis to wait for the command to execute.
 * @param silent     Specifies if the command should be displayed in the screen.
 * @param principals The principals (e.g. RolePrincipal objects) to run the command under
 * @return
 */
protected String executeCommand(final String command, final Long timeout, final Boolean silent, final Principal ... principals) {
    waitForCommandService(command);

    String response;
    final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
    final SessionFactory sessionFactory = getOsgiService(SessionFactory.class);
    final Session session = sessionFactory.create(System.in, printStream, System.err);
    //
    //
    //
    // Snip
```